# Send push notifications to specific audience in android

Tags: android, mysql, amazon-web-services, push-notification, google-cloud-platform

I am making an android application for restaurant system. The users are allowed to subscribe to their favorite restaurants so they don't miss out on discounted deals. I have created a **subscriptions** table in my SQL database which contains **user_id** and **restaurant_id** for all the users who have subscribed to various restaurants. What I'm trying to do is to send push notifications to a group of users whenever their subscribed restaurants post a discounted deals. 
I'm aware of Google and AWS push notification services, but can't figure out how to implement them with this system
Hope someone helps me out with this one! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the API to send to specific users via their "pushtoken".

[Google Docs -> Android FCM client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

You can then add the pushToken to the user row.

Once done, you can set "target groups" and have a table(s) that link users to their requested subscriptions.

Edit: On the other hand, FCM also allows "group pushes" so maybe check out:
[FCM groups](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging)